# Added commented section to output CSV with write_csv()

Tags: r

Is it possible to added comments to an CSV file output with `write_csv()`? The function `read_csv()` has the option `comment = "#"` to skip commented rows.

Example

```
# file created on 2022-05-19 (this is a comment)
date,count
2022-04-19,45
2022-04-20,35
2022-04-21,47
2022-04-22,26
2022-04-23,13
```

Any other options to get to the same result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment line is not part of the specification [RFC4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). However, one can do

```
library(readr)

file <- "data.csv"
data <- iris

write_lines("# foo", file)
data |> colnames() |> paste0(collapse = ",") |> write_lines(file, append = TRUE)
write_csv(data, file, append = TRUE)
```

resulting in a file starting with:

```
# foo
Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width,Petal.Length,Petal.Width,Species
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.9,3,1.4,0.2,setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,setosa
5,3.6,1.4,0.2,setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,setosa
```